# By using JS, it is possible to get a page source, and then respond users with this getting page

Tags: javascript

I want to implement the following things by using JavaScript:

1. using AJAX to get a page source;
2. put in some data into this page source;
3. show the changed page to users.

So it is possible? If so, how?

By the way, I cannot use server side technologies. And if JS is not suitable for it, what client technologies can be used in this case?

Comment: When you say you can't use server side technologies, where is the 'page source' (HTML?) coming from? It sounds like you might benefit from `iframe`s. http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/frames/_IFRAME.html

Comment: I can use AJAX to get the page source. Of course I can use iframe, but the source page of iframe is from different domain, so I also cannot change this source page's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the page you are wanting to get source from is on the same domain, you can get the page source like this:

```
if("XMLHttpRequest" in window){
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
if("ActiveXObject" in window){
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open('GET', "URLofFileYouWantToGetTheSourceFrom", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to display this page to users? Is it possible to open a new window to show this page?